# What is the purpose of SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_STREAM in the context AF_UNIX sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, ipc

I understand that, SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_STREAM corresponds to Connection-less and connection oriented network communication done using INET Address family.

Now i am trying to learn AF_UNIX sockets to carry out IPC between processes running on same host, and there i see we need to specify the sub_socket_type as SOCK_DGRAM Or SOCK_STREAM. I am not able to understand for AF_UNIX sockets, what is the purpose of specifying the sub socket type.

Can anyone pls help understand the significance of SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_STREAM in the context of AF_UNIX sockets ?

Comment: Block special file vs. character special file.

Comment: Can you pls explain the functionality of the two (block and character special file) in the context of IPC using AF_UNIX sockets ?

Answer (score 5):

It happens that TCP is both a stream protocol, and connection oriented, whereas UDP is a datagram protocol, and connectionless. However it is possible to have a connection-oriented datagram protocol. That is what a block special file (or a Windows Mailslot) are.

(You can't have a connectionless stream protocol though, it doesn't make sense, unless `/dev/null` counts)

The flag `SOCK_DGRAM` does not mean the socket is connectionless, it means that the socket is datagram oriented.

A stream-oriented socket (and a character special file like /dev/random or /dev/null) provides (or consumes, or both) a continuous sequence of bytes, with no inherent structure. Structure is provided by interpreting the contents of the stream. Generally speaking there is only one process on either end of the stream.

A datagram-oriented socket, provides (or consumes or both) short messages which are limited in size and self-contained. Generally speaking, the server can receive datagrams from multiple clients using `recvfrom` (which provides the caller with an address to send replies to) and replies to them with `sendto` specifying that address.

Answer (score 0):

The question also confused me for a while, but as Ben said, with socket type is SOCK_STREAM OR SOCK_DGRAM ,they all means the same way to access inter-process communication between client and server.   Under domain AF_UNIX ,it makes not one jot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer, but if it's not, I'd like to be corrected.  So fair warning only the first paragraph am I entirely confident of:

The primary difference is that with SOCK_DGRAM the entire packet is guaranteed to be sent from the client to the server, and received by the server in its entirety when it's received (of course, as long as the buffer in the server is large enough to contain the entire packet).  It also preserves message boundaries - if you do two writes with SOCK_DGRAM, the server will have to do two reads to get both.  This is not true with SOCK_STREAM - at least in theory.

BUT (and let me caution the reader, I may be incorrect about this)

A server cannot send data to the client with SOCK_DGRAM.  You can't reply to a client if the server is SOCK_DGRAM.  There's (apparently) no endpoint or at least I can't get this to work, and I can't find an example, and even using recvfrom and sendto doesn't work.  SOCK_DGRAM is one way, from client to server, if you want to go bidirectional, you need two sockets.

Basically, use SOCK_STREAM, nobody seems to use SOCK_DGRAM with AF_UNIX sockets.

There's a POSSIBILITY (that you should contend with) where you'll get two
messages in a single packet, or a partial packet, and you should code with that in mind.