# How to create multicast-style unix socket?

Tags: linux, go, unix-socket

I'm trying to create multicast-style SOCK_DGRAM unix `.sock` socket where N clients can then connect to and read the messages. OS is GNU/Linux.

Here's my attempt:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    sockFile := `multicast.sock`

    err := syscall.Mkfifo(sockFile, 0o766|syscall.SOCK_DGRAM|syscall.AF_UNIX)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(sockFile) // Remove sock after exit

    fi, err := os.Stat(sockFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    addr, err := net.ResolveUnixAddr("unixgram", fi.Name())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.ListenUnixgram("unixgram", addr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        wb, err := conn.Write([]byte(`hello, world!`))
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf(`err: %v`, err)
            break
        }
        if wb == 0 {
            log.Printf(`we didn't write anything!`)
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
```

Line `conn, err := net.ListenUnixgram("unixgram", addr)` gives error:

```
panic: listen unixgram multicast.sock: bind: address already in use
```

There are no other programs trying to connect to it, so how it is already in use? What's the correct way to listen and create the socket file?

Comment: Why do you assume unix sockets support multicast? They dont.

Comment: @dimich for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008595/what-is-the-purpose-of-sock-dgram-and-sock-stream-in-the-context-af-unix-sockets/51008665#51008665 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61562593/difference-between-unix-domain-sock-dgram-and-sock-seqpacket/61564462#61564462 . Seems to be UDP-like fire-and-forget and one way. ie. multicast to client(s).

Comment: `MkFifo` creates a FIFO (a named pipe), which is **not** the same thing as a Unix socket. Your call to `net.ListenUnixgram` attempts to create the socket, but since you've already created a FIFO at that location, you get your `address already in use` panic.

Comment: @raspi multicast deliveres data to _all_ subscribed clients. To send data over unix socket you should write to descriptor returned by `accept()` which idenifies a single client.